# Copy into postgres with arrays in schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am using Ruby/Rails/Postgres, my table looks like something like (Schema wise):

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_name(
    my_num double precision NOT NULL,
    my_string_arr character varying[] NOT NULL, # this is an array
    my_int_arr integer[] NOT NULL, # this is an array
)
```

In Ruby, I am trying to `copy` into this table like:

```
raw = connection.raw_connection
raw.transaction do
  copy_cmd = <<~SQL
            COPY my_table_name  (
              myNum,my_string_arr,my_int_arr
            )
            FROM STDIN
          SQL

encoder = PG::TextEncoder::CopyRow.new
copy_result = raw.copy_data(copy_cmd, encoder) do
            rows.each do |row|
              raw.put_copy_data(row)
            end
          end
```

Now, `rows` looks something like (just 1 row total):

```
[
 [
   1.15,
   ["abcde"],
   [1234]
 ]
]
```

The error I am getting is:

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "["abcde"]"
DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
CONTEXT:  COPY my_table_name, line 1, column keywords: "["abcde"]"
```

I am unsure how to resolve this, it is one of my first times working with PSQL like this. Any suggestions on how I can make it worth with arrays?

Comment: Why do you want to use copy instead of a normal insert or upsert? Whats the actual problem that this code is solving?

Comment: @max decision from management for some efficiency reasons

Comment: [facepalm]. How much do you trust the input data? Do the strings for example contain quotes or brackets?

Comment: And if they strings can contain quotes, how are they escaped? Do you know how the input file was created?

Comment: You should consult the documentation for the product you are using. 
 https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT